# How to configure HHVM with Apache compiled from source?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hhvm

Today, when HHVM has been updated (Ubuntu 12.04 x64), I try run the *fast_cgi install command*. Like below:

```
➜  ~  sudo /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh 
Checking if Apache is installed
WARNING: Couldn't find Apache2 configuration paths, not configuring
Checking if Nginx is installed
Nginx not found
```

My apache was not found because it's in different location/folder: `/etc/apache247/`

How can I configure this install for a custom apache?

The script for check apache installation is that:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /etc/init.d/hhvm ]
then
        /etc/init.d/hhvm start
fi

#!/bin/bash

apache_check_installed() {
        echo "Checking if Apache is installed"
        if [ \( ! -d /etc/apache2/mods-enabled \) -o \( ! -d /etc/apache2/mods-available \) ]
        then
                echo "WARNING: Couldn't find Apache2 configuration paths, not configuring"
                return 1
        fi
        echo "Detected Apache installation"
        return 0
}
```

---

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the instructions on the [HHVM Wiki](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/FastCGI#apache-24) to manually configure Apache to talk FastCGI to HHVM.

The installation process comes down to enabling the `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_fcgi` modules in Apache, then adding `ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/your/www/root/goes/here/$1` to the `VirtualHost` you want to run HHVM on.